# How to send/receive an array of structure to/from other processor?

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to store structures into an array and use MPI to send it to other processor(rank 0) but when I receive it at rank 0, I can't seem to read the data as it doesn't output it when I want to print. Let's say there are only 2 processors. I'm very new in C.

This my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Status stat;

    struct student {
        unsigned char id;
        unsigned char age;
    };

    struct student *ptrA;
    struct student std;
    struct student oneRow[10];
    struct student rowsPerProcess[30];
    struct student allRows[50];


    if(rank != 0) {

        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {

                if (x == 0) {
                    std.id = 105;
                    std.age = 18;
                } else {
                    std.id = 100;
                    std.age = 20;
                }

                oneRow[x] = std;
            }
            memcpy( rowsPerProcess + 2, oneRow, sizeof(oneRow) );
        }

        MPI_Send(rowsPerProcess, 4, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    } else {
        MPI_Recv(allRows, 20, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
        printf("first student's ID: %c\n", allRows[0].id);
        printf("first student's age: %c\n", allRows[0].age);

        printf("second student's ID: %c\n", allRows[1].id);
        printf("second student's age: %c\n", allRows[1].age);

    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

This is my output, I can print the strings but not the data (eg: `allRows[0].id`):

```
first student's ID:
first student's age: 
second student's ID: 
second student's age:
```

Comment: `memcpy( rowsPerProcess + 2, oneRow, sizeof(oneRow) );` is fishy. And so is the fact that only 4 `MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR` are sent but 20 are received.

Comment: this question is a run-time problem  Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug it.  BTW: include the `#include` statements so we know which headers you included

Comment: regarding: `std.id = 105;
                    std.age = 18;
                } else {
                    std.id = 100;
                    std.age = 20;`  the values are no (generally) ascii printable characters.  Strongly suggest using something like: `printf("first student's ID: %u\n", allRows[0].id);`  (notice the format specifier `%u`  To print those unsigned values

Answer (score 1):

In the sample code provided by you, you don't need to use `memcpy` at all to achieve the desired objective. You can directly send the structure elements from the object `oneRow` itself. The outer loop is also unnecessary. So the below code will make the send and receive work. Also, you are sending `4` characters and receiving `20`.

```
if(rank != 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
                if (x == 0) {
                    std.id = 'a';
                    std.age = 'b';
                } else {
                    std.id = 'c';
                    std.age = 'd';
                }
                   oneRow[x] = std;
        }
        MPI_Send(oneRow, 4, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
       } else {
        MPI_Recv(oneRow, 4, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
        printf("first student's ID: %c\n", oneRow[0].id);
        printf("first student's age: %c\n", oneRow[0].age);
        printf("second student's ID: %c\n", oneRow[1].id);
        printf("second student's age: %c\n", oneRow[1].age);

    }
```

To send structures in MPI, the best way to do is to create **derived data type** using `MPI_Type_create_struct`. If the two characters are aligned in a contiguous memory area (i.e., like in the above example.), you don't need a `derived datatype`.

For a struct:

```
   typedef  struct student_t {
        int  id;
        int age;
    }student;
```

You can create a derived data type in MPI using the following:

```
/* create a type for struct student */
const int nitems=2; // Number of Elements in struct
int blocklengths[2] = {1,1};
MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT}; // data type of struct elements
MPI_Datatype mpi_std_type; //derived type name
MPI_Aint     offsets[2]; // offset of the variable

offsets[0] = offsetof(student, age);
offsets[1] = offsetof(student, id);

MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_std_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_std_type);
```

You can then create the array of struct as `student send[2]` and send it using `MPI_Send()` as `MPI_Send(&send,   2, mpi_std_type, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` using the derived data type (`mpi_std_type`) as the type of the data. Similarly also in the receiver side.

So the resulting program will look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stddef.h>

   typedef  struct student_t {
        int  id;
        int age;
    }student;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int tag = 13;
    int size, rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    /* create a type for struct student */
    const int nitems=2;
    int          blocklengths[2] = {1,1};
    MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
    MPI_Datatype mpi_std_type;
    MPI_Aint     offsets[2];

    offsets[0] = offsetof(student, age);
    offsets[1] = offsetof(student, id);

    MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_std_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_std_type);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0) {
        student send_struct[2];
        send_struct[0].id = 1;
        send_struct[0].age = 2;

        send_struct[1].id = 3;
        send_struct[1].age = 4;
        const int dest = 1;
        MPI_Send(&send_struct,   2, mpi_std_type, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        printf("Rank %d: sent structure student\n", rank);
    }
    if (rank == 1) {
        MPI_Status status;
        const int src=0;

        student recv_struct[2];

        MPI_Recv(&recv_struct,   2, mpi_std_type, src, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("Rank %d: Received: id = %d age = %d \n", rank,
                 recv_struct[0].id, recv_struct[0].age);

        printf("Rank %d: Received: id = %d age = %d \n", rank,
                 recv_struct[1].id, recv_struct[1].age);
    }

    MPI_Type_free(&mpi_std_type);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OT: the name `send` is a well known function from the C library.  It is a very bad idea to name variables the same as C library functions.

Comment: Changed the variable name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've understand quite a lot from your explanation but what I'm also trying to do is to accumulate the array from rank1 in the array from rank 0. meaning my array in rank 0 will be like [ {id: 2, age: 18}, {id: 3, age:19}, {id: 4, age:20}, {id: 5, age:21} ] . Id 2 and 3 is being generated in rank 0 and Id 4 and 5 will be generated in rank 1 but rank 1 will send its array to rank 0 then rank 0 will take the data and append to its own array resulting to have the final array like this.

Comment: So you have a structure array `allRows` which stores own values and receives the values from others. Also each individual process has a `oneRow` which stores its own value.So, your goal is to send the data in struct of `oneRow` from all processes to rank 0.  To do that, all processes can send its own values using using `MPI_Send(oneRow,...)`  and use a loop inside rank 0 to receive from n process. While receiving  `MPI_Recv(&allRows[i],..,MPI_ANY_SOURCE,..) `, you can append the values at struct  `allRows ` in the desired index by using  `&allRows[i] `.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to log what you need by following steps,

1) You need to change `count` to be the same amount. So replace `20` with `4`.

2) Replace `%c` to `%d` to see the integer values. Otherwise you will see useless character symbols.

Comment: Following the above steps won't fix the problem. From my run, It will only print 0 instead of an empty space. Have you tried it on your system?

Comment: Yes, it prints the expected values not zeros.